# Repeat component for each key and value in Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JavaScript [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of key/value pairs. I want to repeat render some React components, to display each key/value from the Map inside a table. I'm trying it this way, but I don't get any rows displayed if the myMap contains the following entries:

```
run: 2
test: 2
```

[image]

```
export const KeyValueTable = (props) => {

  const text = props.text;
  const myMap = getMyMap(text);

  return (
    <Table>
      <Head>
        <Cell><Text>Key</Text></Cell>
        <Cell><Text>Value</Text></Cell>
      </Head>

      {[...myMap].map((keyValuePair) => (
        <Row>
          <Cell><Text>key = {keyValuePair[0]}</Text></Cell>
          <Cell><Text>value = {keyValuePair[1]}</Text></Cell>
        </Row>
      ))}
    </Table>
  )
};
```

My `getMyMap` function:

```
export const getMyMap = (text) => {
    
    var myArray = text.split(" ");
    var myMap = new Map();
    

    for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        const word = myArray[i];
        myMap[word] = myMap[word] + 1 || 1;
    }
 
    return myMap;
}
```

What is a highly performant, elegant way to iterate the `Map` and repeat render components with the key+value of each item in the `Map`

Comment: Can you provide sample myMap value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this using `Map.prototype.entries`

```
export const KeyValueTable = (props) => {

  const myProp = props.myProp;
  const myMap = getMyMap(myProp);

  return (
    <Table>
      <Head>
        <Cell><Text>Key</Text></Cell>
        <Cell><Text>Value</Text></Cell>
      </Head>

      {Object.entries(myMap).map(([key, value]) => (
        <Row>
          <Cell><Text>key = {key}</Text></Cell>
          <Cell><Text>value = {value}</Text></Cell>
        </Row>
      ))}
    </Table>
  )
};
```

Comment: Thanks, the compiler is warning me that `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'IterableIterator<[any, any]>'.`

Comment: @Izzy - You can use `Object.entries`. Like `Object.entries(myMap).map(([key, value]) => (`

Comment: @Izzy I edited my answer now it should work

Comment: Thanks @R4ncid I still get no rows output using your updated code. I updated my question to show the function that gets the `Map`, and the actual content of the `Map` during debugging

Comment: @user1672994 was right `Object.entries` was the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Hey This might be helpful I used a sample code at my end:

```
export const KeyValueTable = (props) => {
  const map1 = new Map();

  map1.set("a", 1);
  map1.set("b", 2);
  map1.set("c", 3);
  console.log(map1);
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Key</th>
          <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {[...map1].map((keyValuePair, index) => (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>key = {keyValuePair[0]}</td>
          <td>value = {keyValuePair[1]}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

I used basic HTML tags as was not sure which library you were using.

Comment: The reason you are not getting any rows is that there is no table body in your code. @Izzy